# PHP get the current day and test if it a sunday or saturday

Tags: php, date

I want to get the current day from a date, and if it's a Firday, I want to set the date for next Monday.
Any idea please to resolve it

Comment: [PHP Docs](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: I answered a question like this not long ago.

Comment: can you send me a link please

Comment: You've been given an answer below. Try that.

Comment: Click on Mark Baker's link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $date =  "11-3-2016";
 echo date('w', strtotime($date)); //5
 echo date('l', strtotime($date));//Friday
```